# GraphHopper offline routing using .osm.pbf file

Tags: dictionary, routes, openstreetmap, graphhopper, mapsforge

I downloaded the .map file and display with Mapsforge. Now, I want to find route offline using GraphHopper.

Can anyone give me an example link?

What do I need to do for offline routing with GraphHopper and what files I need and where to put the file in a mobile directory?

Comment: Isn't all of that explained in the GraphHopper documentation? What have you tried so far?

Comment: docs -> index -> developers -> android https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/master/docs/android/index.md#maps